# Exploding pies: Strange results from geom_arc_bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart

I am trying to use R to make a pie chart with the wedges separated in a uniform manner. This should be possible using geom_arc_bar() and the 'explode' setting in ggplot. But I am getting strange results

I tried this code and got a pie chart where the wedges are not uniformly separated:

```
library(ggforce)
library(ggplot2)

pie <- data.frame( days_in_each_month = c(31,  28,  31,  30,  31,  30,  31,  31,  30,  31,  30,  31),
                    months = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"))

p <- ggplot() + theme_no_axes() + coord_fixed() + theme(legend.position="none")
#define the inner set of background wedges
p <- p + geom_arc_bar(data = pie, stat = 'pie', aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = .1, r = .5, amount = days_in_each_month, fill = months, explode = 0.02))

p
```

[image]

Some experimentation revealed that I can get explode to work a little better if I specify the explode parameter for each wedge and provide zeros for the last three wedges. For example:

```
pie <- data.frame( days_in_each_month = c(31,  28,  31,  30,  31,  30,  31,  31,  30,  31,  30,  31),
                   months = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"))

expl <- c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0)

p <- ggplot() + theme_no_axes() + coord_fixed() + theme(legend.position="none")
#define the inner set of background wedges
p <- p + geom_arc_bar(data = pie, stat = 'pie', aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = .1, r = .5, amount = days_in_each_month, fill = months, explode = expl))

p
```

[image]

BUT....if I change any of the zeros in expl to something else, the expanded pie chart is uneven again:

```
pie <- data.frame( days_in_each_month = c(31,  28,  31,  30,  31,  30,  31,  31,  30,  31,  30,  31),
                   months = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12"))

expl <- c(0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0.02, 0, 0, 0.2)

p <- ggplot() + theme_no_axes() + coord_fixed() + theme(legend.position="none")
#define the inner set of background wedges
p <- p + geom_arc_bar(data = pie, stat = 'pie', aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = .1, r = .5, amount = days_in_each_month, fill = months, explode = expl))

p
```

[image]

I am at a loss to explain this behavior. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be easier to do this in vanilla ggplot using `coord_polar`

```r
ggplot(pie, aes(ymin = 1, ymax = 3, 
                xmin = cumsum(dplyr::lag(days_in_each_month + 1, 1, 0)) + 1,
                xmax = cumsum(days_in_each_month + 1) - 1, fill = months)) +
  geom_rect(color = 'navy') +
  coord_polar() +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 378)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 3.5)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for these alternatives. However, I need the gaps between the wedges to be uniform as opposed to expanding. I've got to end up with a very specific plot like the one here: https://birdsoftheworld.org/bow/species/mallar3/cur/multimedia?media=figures. I've already written the code to make the more complicated plot, and it used to work. Something seems to have changed in ggplot that broke the 'explode' parameter. Is this just a bug that cannot be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

```
ggplot() + 
  theme_no_axes() + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  geom_arc_bar(data = pie |> dplyr::mutate(start = 2*pi*(0:(nrow(pie)-1))/(nrow(pie))), 
               stat = 'arc_bar', 
               aes(x0 = 0, y0 = 0, r0 = .2, r = .5, 
                   start = start, end = start + 0.9*2*pi/nrow(pie),
                   fill = months))
```

[image]